# General iOS File Finder

Tags: ios, swift

In my App I would like to import various document types (video, audio, photo's, pdf and text). I can use UIImagePickerController for the photo's and videos. I can use UIDocumentPickerViewController to get all file types from an iCloud drive - but this does not seem to find any files I have created on this device (and not added to iCloud). I feel like I am missing something fundamental. NSOpenPanel is there for OSX, is there nothing equivalent for iOS?

Comment: The short answer is NO. There is no NSOpenPanel equivalent  for iOS

Comment: But you can easily create a table view or a collection view and populate it with the current directory files

Comment: Thanks Leo, but are the video and audio files recorded by the device in the "current directory"? Are they not elsewhere?

Comment: Of course not. But You can use the image picker to get them from the camera roll and save/move them to the Documents Directory if needed

Comment: Thanks for your help Leo. Have you used UIDocumentPickerViewController can you confirm it is only good for iCloud docs?

Comment: A UIDocumentPickerViewController object lets the user select documents or destinations outside your app’s sandbox. (That's where your documents directory it is located)

Comment: So isn't that an equivalent to NSOpenPanel? Sorry for my inability to understand.

Comment: I said outside (everything that it is not local resource) NSOpenPanel was originally meant to open local files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIDocumentPickerViewController can only access files in iCloud or a similar service (eg DropBox). There is no way to access files outside your app's sandbox.  They must first be moved (or copied) to iCloud.